# jQuery updateing multiple #divs, one mysql_query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

A bit complicated, but ill do my best to explain my question.

I have a main file, dashboard.html.
Within that I have a jQuery function to load the mysql_query every 15sec to get the 15 or so variables that I need. (This is a financial/sales webapp...the sales agents want near realtime updates of the sales, orders, $earned..etc) which are displayed in a #div with multiple listitems contained within. No issues with this with the approach that every 15sec, query, then entire div is updated all at once. Because of this I have not attached an Jquery effect (namely fadeIn/fadeOut) to it, as then the entire div is constantly fading. Not the visual effect I would like, but as it stands, it works.

My Goal: To be able to do the mysql_query every 15sec. Grab the variables (which Im already doing currently. But now, I would like to be able to update ONLY the ListItem that has changed and attach the fade effect to just that item, not the entire #div as a whole.

What Im trying to avoid is separating out the query to 15 separate querys, as that obviously that is not efficient.

Hopefully that makes some sense to everyone. Code can be provided, but I dont think it will help at this point .. I need to understand what approach I need to go to develop the correct code. Thanks everyone for your anticipated help.

EDIT: Im adding a bit of code to help clarify where I stand:
dashboard.html

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
$('#order_jq').load('stats_count.php')
}, 15000); // refresh every 15 seconds
```

and then in the body:

```
<div class="span8">
<div id="order_jq" class="centerContent">
Patiently loading stats ...
</div><!-- End id="ortder_jq -->
</div><!-- End .span8 -->
```

stats_count.php consists of (stripped down for clarity)

```
<?php
require "database/connect2.php";
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT .... NORMAL QUERY...NOTHING FANCY HERE")
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{$orders = number_format($row['ordercount']);
$annual_order = number_format($row['annual_order']);
}
```

and lastly contained within stats_count.php I also include the list items:

```
<ul class="bigBtnIcon">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon entypo-icon-phone"></span>
        <span class="txt">Orders</span>
        <span class="notification"><?php echo $orders?></span>
      </a>
     </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon brocco-icon-mic"></span>
          <span class="txt">Auburn</span>
          <span class="notification blue"><?php echo $annual_order ?></span>
        </a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

-D

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple divs to be updated, you have to select them with their class ".class" not id "#id"..

To create mysql_query every 15 seconds, you need to make setInterval(function(),15000) where function must make ajax request to some page where to do this query..

I can advice you to use jQuery Ajax for those requests..

Comment: So I have the query updating the entire #div without problems, every 15sec. That works great. So the .class .. I guess now im confused. How do I associate the update ajax function which loads the count.php query string to the appropriate #div within the dahsboard.html?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about what format your data is being returned in its difficult to get into specifics but the general approach would be:

1. store current values into an object,
2. create a new object with your incoming values
3. cycle through the properties of the obect comparing incoming values
   to existing values
4. update individual panels (via classes or more specific id's)
5. turn incoming values object into current values object in
   preperation for next sql query

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, this could be done like this :
- all your listitems must  have a class attribute let's say "list_items".
- after getting data with Jquery you can do a jquery.each() on the list_items, this way you can check if the value of that list item == the new value if not you update your list item.
I hope this answers a little bit your question.

Comment: ok. Ill take a look at the .each function. I wasnt familiar with it until now. But the concept seems good!